# VB.Net - Display Yes/No in a Combobox but have a value of 1/0

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This one is really kicking my butt, i'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a combobox on my form that i need to display a "yes" and a "no" instead of a "0" and "1" BUT to process a "0" and "1" depending on the selection. Make sense?

[image: Screenshot of my form here.]

I have the 0 and 1 sitting in the Data > Items > Collection properties of the combobox.

I have tried playing around with the DisplayMember property and the ValueMember property but i cant seem to get these working.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should bind your control. Create a list of objects, e.g. `Tuples`, that have two properties: one for the text to display and one for the number. You then set the `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `DataSource` of your control appropriately. Before you ask, no I will not be writing the code. I'm pointing you in the right direction and it's up to you to go that way and learn what needs to be learned. There are plenty of examples of binding a `ComboBox` around.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney i appreciate the response, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll go check out 'binding a combobox' and see what i can do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Data > Items > Collection properties of the combobox
Delete every line in there and add the following, (in the same order)

```
NO
YES
```

Now double click on your combobox in  the form in design mode.

In the event subroutine for the combobox - selected index changed event, add the following:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    UserChoseReloadSurvey = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

And that will save either a 1 or 0 in a variable named UserChoseReloadSurvey.
Taking it for granted that you have an integer variable named UserChoseReloadSurvey